# How to print a MySQL query results as XML in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I would like to output as XML, the results of a MySQL query.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For MySQL => PHP : use raw PHP functions like **mysql_query()**, **mysql_fetch_assoc()** etc., or PDO, or an ORM...
- For PHP array => XML, here is an example: [How to convert array to SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml-in-php). And another good one: http://snipt.net/robertbanh/php-array-to-xml/